# Reduction in reputation

Tags: discussion, support

Magically some 10 reputation points disappeared from my account. I don't know how. Is there any known explanation? Or something has gone wrong with my eyes.

Comment: One of the answers is definitely correct below but I can't accept one answer because I am not sure which one is correct to my context.

Comment: I can confirm that Ivo has the correct answer. Your reduction in reputation correlated with the deletion of some questions which I thought had triggered a reputation recalculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question got migrated to Bicycles: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/pain-in-the-lower-back-and-neck-during-cycling

Hence you lost the rep here, but you gained it on Bicycles

Answer (score 3):

Could be that someone removed an upvote on one of your answers, or that an answer (or more likely the whole question, if e.g. closed) was deleted from the system. When this happens, reputation goes with it.

This might help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/147089

Answer (score 2):

<s>I recently ran through some old and off-topic questions on this site that are not a good fit and deleted a few of them. The reduction in reputation is likely from that.</s>

Ivo is correct that you lost 10 reputation due to a migration. Your original question (before it was migrated to Bicycles) on Fitness was deleted two days ago which corresponds to the reduction in reputation. The system automatically culled your migrated question and removed it.